# How to use a Windows domain user (service account) to run a container with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server

Suppose I have a .tar image and docker-compose.yml, and I use `docker-compose up -d some_web_service` command to run the container, how to run it in a domain user (service account) different from logon user?

The docker-compose.yml should look like

```yaml
services:
  some_web_service:
    image: "some_web_service:1.0.0"
    platform: windows
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "44301:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SomeWebService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - A=some text
      - B=12345
```

The machine is a Windows Server 2016 or 2019 with Docker Engine running as service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the documentation of Group Managed Service Accounts?
Most of the Microsoft documentation today focus on Kubernetes, but there are notes there on Docker only environments. Essentially, what you need is a gMSA account to be used for the application authentication. Then, the container host will perform the authentication on-behalf of the application.

There's a whole architecture for that to work, including a credential spec so your host know how to map the application to credentials, etc.

The more specific answer to your question is that you need to configure the application to use Network Service. For example, if the application is running on IIS, you can use:

```
RUN %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set AppPool DefaultAppPool -'processModel.identityType':NetworkService
```

More details on other types of apps and how to configure them here: https://cda.ms/4q1

On Docker Swarm, you can use:

```
docker service create --credential-spec "file://contoso_webapp01.json" --hostname "WebApp01" <image name>
```

Comment: Is there any docker-compose way to do similar thing?

Comment: Not documented, but I assume it's something that can be done.